# Html <li> tags don't show up

Tags: html

Im currently experimenting with the html world. And i found this on a site called w3schoold but it doesnt work.

Can anyone tell me why i doesnt work?

```
<p>An unordered list:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee<li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
<li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
<li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `<li>Coffee<li>` should be `<li>Coffee</li>`. Notice the closed `li`

Comment: I will keep that in mind for the furture @AdrianoRepetti

Comment: Works fine for me. Just an empty bullet because of your type in the the closing tag for "Coffee".

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti , actually w3schools it's pretty useful , especially for beginners .

Comment: To check your code I recommend the w3c validator to understand what error you made. But here as @Dima answered you do not close the first li tag

Answer (score 1):

Your first `<li>` tag not closed
it should be like this 
change from :

```
<li>Coffee<li>
```

to:

```
<li>Coffee</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The very first `<li>` is not closed properly: `</li>`. Other than that, this works fine.

```html
<p>An unordered list:</p>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Sidenote: This is why one should avoid [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/). Head over to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) to find a better learning experience.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about MDN